# notepad ++ - need help docking windows

Tags: notepad++

My NppFTP window used to be docked on the right, like this:

[image: docked]

But, I clicked something accidentally, and now, it's detached as a separate window:

[image: undocked]

I can manually resize the window, and move it around. I can also dock it horizontally at the top by double-clicking the title. But I can't figure out how to re-dock it on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Just double click on the top of the window,

or move it to the right border of the main window.

Comment: Double clicking docks it horizontally at the top, not vertically on the right. And moving it to the right doesn't dock it...that just leaves it as a free-floating separate window.

Comment: @JEP: The mouse pointer must be on the right border. What version of Npp do you have? Here, I have `v7.5.6` and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using 7.5.1.

Comment: I verified that this does work.

Answer (score -1):

right click on separator...rotate left.

Comment: OP is asking how to re-dock a window, not how to change the orientation of the split.

Comment: Whilst I think this is a correct answer (or could be anyway), is it possible to flesh it out, such as by adding a screen shot?

Comment: This does not dock the window on the right.